# How to apply shaders to the final HDMI video output of a computer?

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, video-capture, video-card

I'd like to be able to apply a custom final shader to the HDMI output of my PC before its sent out to my monitor.

For example, let's say I'm watching a youtube video of an old documentary; I'd like to be able to apply a shader to the entire display to emulate the look of an old CRT tv. Does anyone have some pointers as to how I could achieve this solely through software?

I have a GeForce graphics card on Windows 10. I'd also like to be able to do this with MacOS if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have control over video at this presentation stage. When you are watching YouTube video, presumably via web browser, the browser applicaton renders the video and delivers it to the Desktop Window Manager, which combines data from applications and OS itself into a video frame to "send" to connected monitor over HDMI link. Windows does not offer you services to alter the composed image, so you cannot apply your shader at this stage, especially using OpenGL because why OpenGL.

You have a few options but none of then are really simple.

You can have YouTube stuff presented onto one monitor and then use Desktop Duplication API to capture back the composed look for the entire monitor, use it as an input texture for your shader, apply the effect and then display the output on another monitor in your player application.

Alternatively you can implement and media player yourself, which takes video from YouTube and then depending on API or library you are using you would modify the video frame sequence you are playing as you need. Having the picture ready you display the video in a player-like application.

Comment: "I think in the end I might just end up making custom hardware that sits between the computer and display." You can do that with a PC with a HDMI capture and a GPU. However, doing so will add additional latency, if you're lucking you can get it down to 1 to 2 frames max, but even that will require much effort.

Comment: Also note that AMD on it's firepro/radeon pro worksation cards supports [DOPP](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/DOPP) which is exactly what you want: post-process (or completely replace) the windows compositor's textrue before it goes out to the monitor.